# Jersey asynchronous multi threaded response?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to create asynchronous Jersey RESTful webap.

The following code is used to test implementation but it is not working.

```
@Path("/demox")
public class RESTClient {

    public static boolean ran = false;

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @ManagedAsync
    public void test(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) throws InterruptedException {
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(ar -> ar.resume(
                Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out")
                        .build()));
        if(!ran) {
            while(true) {
                ran = true;
            }
        }
        asyncResponse.resume("REST IS OKAY! ");
    }
}
```

The way I test it is I open the url twice. But the second tab always waits for the first one to timeout. So this is obviously not working.

Servlet file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>services,org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is working. Accordingly to [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html):

> By the AsyncResponse parameter into a resource method we tell the Jersey runtime that the method is supposed to be invoked using the asynchronous processing mode, that is the client connection should not be automatically closed by the underlying I/O container when the method returns. Instead, the injected AsyncResponse instance (that represents the suspended client request connection) will be used to explicitly send the response back to the client using some other thread. In other words, Jersey runtime knows that when the asyncGet method completes, the response to the client may not be ready yet and the processing must be suspended and wait to be explictly resumed with a response once it becomes available.

Comment: Yes. But how would you explain the waiting time needed for the second browser tab to load? All tabs that are opened after the first one wait for it to finish loading, and then they load instantly.

Comment: mentioned link is now broken, it can be looked up at: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html